# Connection from QlikView to SnowFlake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, qlikview

I'm trying to connect from `QlikView` to snowflake in order to download data to `qvd`

I've installed the necessary driver:
[image: Driver]

Filled all the blue blanks:
[image: Credentials]

Trying to connect from `QlikView`:
[image: Connect]

After I press the test connection I'm get the following error after a long time:
[image: Error]

Comment: it actually looks like you have no network connection

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. Opened the Server for network connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Zephro mentioned, it seems there's a connectivity issue on your side. Could you please use SnowCD to ensure that you can access to the Snowflake service?

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowcd.html

Download the SnowCD for your operation system (Windows/Mac/Linux are supported).

First run the following command:

```
SELECT SYSTEM$WHITELIST();
```

Then save the output to a JSON file (test.json), and run the SnowCD with the JSON file name as first parameter:

```
snowcd test.json
```